# MultiBinding with PriorityBinding workaround

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, converters

I'm currently working on an app in which borders are displaying objects in a "change-state". The visibility of these borders is controlled using "BorderThickness" and a priority binding (the visibility is set in a converter). Now there's a request to make the thickness of the change-state border configurable (obtained at runtime).

My initial attempt was changing the converter into a multi-binding converter:

```
<Border.BorderThickness>
    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource StringToBorderThickness}">
        <PriorityBinding>
            <Binding Path="Change1" />
            <Binding Path="Change2" />
        </PriorityBinding>
        <Binding Path="DataContext.Settings.ChangeStateThickness" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}" />
    </MultiBinding>
</Border.BorderThickness>
```

This does NOT work because WPF does not support MultiBinding+PriorityBinding at the same time (as it turns out).

Can anyone recommend a workaround? I can't remove the Priority Binding and I can't find a different way to control the border visibility (BorderVisibility also makes the object IN the border invisible)

Thank you.

Comment: Can't you just put the Change1 and Change2 bindings to the normal bindings collection of the MultiBinding, and then handle their values in the converter?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I did consider that option, but the values Change1 and Change2 are async and I can't know if either, one or both or the values will be available or when they'll be available. So I'd have to make the ValueConverter async too.. is this possible?

Comment: "The values are async", what does that mean? A C# property can't be async.

Comment: Async is probably the wrong way to describe it. What I meant is: PriorityBinding refreshes if a new high Priority Value is added. Anyway, I've solved it the way you suggested by implementing it's functionallity into the converter. Thanks :)

Comment: The MultiBinding is also refreshed whenever one of its child bindings produces a new value.